# Polarization current introduced by induced charge?

Tags: electromagnetism, solid-state-physics, plasma-physics

Should we count the current density that introduced by the movement of induced charge as free current or magnetized current or neither? And why?

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit more. The question is interesting. Please tell the boundary conditions, are the electrons moved in a wire or is it a stream of free moving electrons? Is the wire bended into a coil or not, ...

Comment: I think what I'm asking for is just a clarification of certain concepts which can be discussed without specific condition. But if you want, I was actually thinking about a TEM p-wave incidents in to a dielectric medium from vacuum (at some angle), so there's induced surface charge density that will generate a surface polarization current density.

Answer (score 2):

No, polarization current is separate from magnetic current and free current. For this answer I will refer to the current densities add simply current, but remember that in all mentioned relationships the units are $A/m^2.$

The total current in a medium is $J = J_f + J_m + J_p$ where $J_f$ is induced by change in free charge density, $J_m$ is induced by the magnetization field $M,$ and $J_p$ is induced by change in polarization charge density.

Not a lot of time is given to polarization current in any of the sources I've found. This is possibly due to the fact that the polarization field only changes until the charge stabilizes so for most analysis the polarization charge has reached it's equilibrium.

Comment: Oh so you mean $J_p$ only exists as long as the bound charges are moving due to the externally applied electric field? If the electric field was not time varying that would mean it exists for a very short time span. But if the electric field was constantly changing and the bound charges were also moving we would have a time varying polarization current that may never quite become zero?